# opencv houghlines2 linelength is way to short

Tags: c#, opencv, detection, hough-transform

I have a line with an angle of 205 degrees and a length of  77 pixels. (Found with sqrt(x^2+y^2)) Kind of like this. The measurements are not correct on this image, it is just for showing you what i mean.
[image]

I am performing houghlines2 like this:

```
image.HoughLines2(storage, HoughLinesMethod.Probalistic, 2, Cv.PI / 90, 1, lineLength, 0);
```

I've added a for-loop to make sure, that I detect the line. When the lineLength is 44, I finally find the line with the houghlines2 method - see image below.

[image]

How come I have to go all the way down to 44? I need to be able to find it at "almost" the correct length, +- 10 is okay, but -33 is too much.

I need answer on how to perform the houghtransform, not a lot of links to different readings. I have been reading on a lot of pages, but I can't figure it op.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and take a shot at this... I have been using Hough Transform from OpenCV in C++ this summer, and I have never actually gotten good results with `HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC`.

I have a general idea why a standard Hough Transform sometimes does not detect a line, and it might give you an explanation why this also is not working:
When you apply the `HoughLines2` method, you have to specify the *rho* and *theta* argument. Now, it this arguments are not set up correctly (e.g. the bins are too wide apart, theta is too large) it is possible to "miss" parts of the lines.

You said you did some reading, so you know the general idea. Now, if you try to imagine a line that spanns from `(0, 0)` to `(500, 1)`. If you know how digitally straight lines are drawn, than you know that this is usually displayed kind of like to lines: one from `(0, 0)` to `(250, 0)` and the other one from `(250, 1)` to `(500, 1)`. If your Hough angle is now big (e.g. bigger then the angle the line is under), it will never actually "catch" all those points in the same bin, and will basically detect two lines of the length *250*. Not just "a little" smaller, but actually a lot. Since the `HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC` not only needs the pixels to fall in to the same "bin" but also requires them to be more or less continuous in the original picture, that probably adds yet another layer of complexness to this story.

Other explanation that might be applicable if you consider detecting only line *segments* is that the minimum length is not determined by the real number of pixels, but by the number of pixels that end up in the same bin. Now, because of the same thing mentioned above, all of the 77 pixels might not actually be in the bin, and thus the shortness.

All of this is, of course, just a basic principle of what I think might be causing the problem. Hope it helps though. My advice would be: try playing around with the "rho" and "theta" parameters or otherwise, just detect normal lines. Those methods are implemented a little better in OpenCV then this version IMO.

Comment: Would it be possible to do some bluring or something like that, and thereby achieve a "long line"? Have you tried this or something like it?

Comment: You might try some blurring - but then you might get multiple responses. What I would try in your place is a) playing around with rho & theta and b) detecting *lines* and not *segments* and then just detecting the segments yourself - e.g. travel along the proposed line pixel by pixel, and when there's more of 3 non-black pixels, or pixel ratio in the last 10 pixels falls under 60% or somesuch - you get the end of the line (very similar for begining - just inverted colors)